# What is the width and height of the "Chance" and "Community Chest" cards in Monopoly?

Tags: monopoly, playing-cards

What is the exact width and height of Monopoly's "Chance" and "Community Chest" cards in inches?

I do not have access to mine (a 1950's set) at the moment, but they seemed to be around 3⅛ (3.125) inches x 2 inches (but may have changed with different editions, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

According to [Monopoly Land](https://www.monopolyland.com/monopoly-board-dimensions/):

> Monopoly Chance and Community Chest cards are 3 1/8 inches tall and 2 inches wide. If you work in centimetres, that’s 8 cm tall and 5 cm wide.

Comment: Of course those aren't 100% accurate, as 2 inches = 5.08 centemeters.

Comment: "Monopoly Land" has errors, such as: "In Mpnopoly, Chance cards, Community Chest cards and Title Deed cards are all the same size." I'm not referring to their "Mpnopoly" typo, I'm referring to the fact that the Title Deed cards are definitely not the same size as Chance and Community Chest (in my copy or this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuWvMgYv03g ). Additionally, they do not show measurements of Chance / Community Chest card sizes (as they do with properties). I appreciate the answer, but questionable sites like that with no official authority are why I'm asking this question!